# Generating a random number of child records

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child

I am successfully using the code below to generate 20 parent records with 15 children each. How can I modify this code to generate a random number (ie 5-20) random child records for each parent.

CREATE TABLE emp_info
    (
       empid INTEGER,
       empname VARCHAR2(50)
    );

```
CREATE TABLE  emp_attendance    
(empid INTEGER,
 start_date DATE,
 end_date DATE
 );
```

--  option with CTE

```
insert all 
  when rn = 1 then into emp_info   (empid, empname) values (id, name)
  when  1 = 1 then into emp_attendance (empid, start_date, end_date) 
               values (id, d1, d1 + dbms_random.value (0, .75))
with t as (select nvl(max(empid), 0)     maxid from emp_info)
select ceil(maxid + level/15) id,
       case mod(maxid + level, 15) when 1 then 1 end rn, 
       dbms_random.string('U',     dbms_random.value(3, 15)) name, 
       trunc(sysdate) +    dbms_random.value (1, 30) d1
  from t connect by level <= 20 * 15;
-- 20 parent records 15 children each
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `ROW_NUMBER` function as follows:

-- see the inline comments for explanation

```
insert all 
  when rn = 1 then into emp_info   (empid, empname) values (id, name)
  when  1 = 1 then into emp_attendance (empid, start_date, end_date) 
               values (id, d1, d1 + dbms_random.value (0, .75))
select * from 
(
with t as (select nvl(max(empid), 0)     maxid from emp_info)
select ceil(maxid + level/15) id,
       case mod(maxid + level, 15) when 1 then 1 end rn, 
       dbms_random.string('U',     dbms_random.value(3, 15)) name, 
       trunc(sysdate) +    dbms_random.value (1, 30) d1,
       case when row_number() over (partition by ceil(maxid + level/15) 
                                        order by level) > 5 then 
       dbms_random.value(5, 20)
       else 5 end as random_val -- added this expression as column
  from t connect by level <= 20 * 20 -- changed it from 15 to 20
)
  where random_val <= 12; -- this is random number less than 20
```

Comment: I don't understand your output as I am seeing decimal for the random number and - for the rn. Can you modify the insert statement and run this query. The empid should be sequenced but the count should be random

     SELECT empid, count(*) from emp_attendance group by empid order by empid

    EMPID    COUNT(*)
    1    15
    2    15
    3    15
    4    15
   ….
   ….
     20    15

Comment: Updated!! Check it now!!

Comment: Thanks it looks like it works but I have a question. Does this line of code dbms_random.value(5, 20)
Mean a min of 5 child records or a max of 20 records. Also, what does <=12  mean? Why not 11 or 9? Thanks for your patience and help

Comment: `12` is random number, You can use 15 or 13. whatever you want. `dbms_random.value(5, 20)` will generate a random number between 5 and 20

Comment: So 12 is the upper limit of child records per empid and 5 is the lower limit?

Comment: No it is just a random number. Upper limit is 20 and lower limit is 5

Comment: Yes, because we are taking first 5 records and then for 6-20 records, generating random number between 5-20. We can then compare with any number between 5-20 so that it can give us any number of records.

Comment: If you're saying there is a random number of child records 5-20 then why is this needed 
  where random_val <= 12;  should it be random_val <=20 since 20 is the max or not needed at all? Can you please clarify?
Sorry for all the questions

Comment: See. First of all we are generating 20 records and taking 5 records (constant) after that 6 to 20 records, generates the random number and in where clause compare it with again random number(12) so that you will get random records for each parent id

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but can you tell me why I'm not getting a distributed amount of child records SELECT empid, count(*) 
    from  emp_attendance
     group by empid order by empid 


    EMPID    COUNT(*)
    1    20
    2    20
    3    20
    4    18
    5    19
    6    20
    7    20
    8    19
    9    20
    10    20   
    11    19
    ……
    …….
     50    20